# Count product combinations which are under same customer

Tags: sql, count, combinations

I have table like this:

| Customer_nr | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 11111 | Table |
| 22222 | Sofa |
| 333333 | Table |
| 444444 | Closet |
| 11111 | Bed |

How can I find the number of product combination that a bought by same customer?

Out come should be like that:

| Product A | Product B | Count of combination |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Table | Bed | 245 |

It mean that 245 customers bought table and bed

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Please can you edit your question and tag the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a self-join and aggregate as the following:

```
select t.Product Product_A, d.Product Product_B,
  count(*) com_cnt
from table_name t join table_name d
on d.Customer_nr = t.Customer_nr and
   d.Product > t.Product
group by t.Product, d.Product
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/nEy9XUpZ)

Comment: In table I have 500k rows, but for some product combination it counts more than 6 millions combination

Comment: Do you have duplicates in your table? the same customer bought the same combinations many times?

Comment: All good, found a problem, thanks for help

Comment: What if I have dublicates that same customer bought the same combinations many times but I need it to count as one?

Comment: You need to add `DISTINCT` inside the `COUNT` aggregate function in that specific case.

Comment: Just use `count(distinct t.Customer_nr)` instead of `count(*)` https://dbfiddle.uk/6P6Ub8LL

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count a specific combination, then use `group by` and `having` :

First, identify the customers who purchased those products:

```
select customer_nr
from mytable
where product in ('Table', 'Bed')
group by customer_nr
having count(distinct product) = 2
```

Then count how many customers there are:

```
select 'Table' as 'product A', 'Bed' as 'product B', count(distinct customer_nr) 
from (
  select customer_nr
  from mytable
  where product in ('Table', 'Bed')
  group by customer_nr
  having count(distinct product) = 2
) as s
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/jtMm676w) on mysql